# Unexpected rounding-off from DATETIME2 to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

First of all, it may not have a practical use but just want to know how/why this is happening.

When I am trying to assign a DATETIME2 value to a DATETIME variable, there happens an unexpected roundoff in the value.

**Sample SQL :**

```
DECLARE @DT DATETIME
DECLARE @DT2 DATETIME2

SET @DT2='2015-07-23 18:35:34.8815038'
SELECT @DT=@DT2

SELECT @DT2 AS [DATETIME2],@DT AS [DATETIME]
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
DATETIME2                             DATETIME
------------------------------------------------------------        
2015-07-23 18:35:34.8815038    |     2015-07-23 18:35:34.883
```

Now, I am not able to find the cause why *8815038* nano seconds is rounded off to *883* milliseconds against expected *881* or *882* milliseconds.

If any body knows the exact explaination to this, please share here. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that in [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type, you only have .000, .003 and .007 fraction of a second as smallest increments.

Try this:

```
select cast('2015-01-01 00:00:00.882' as datetime)
select cast('2015-01-01 00:00:00.884' as datetime)
```

And you'll see that both are rounded to .883

Comment: Perfect ! 
Any reference link to know why these type of fractions of seconds are available?

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri No official reference, but this guy explains it pretty well: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server/. Seems that datetime is not stored neither as floating point, nor as integer.

Comment: I found another reference , in fact it's a MSDN document. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx .Datetime is not accurate on millisecond level but Accuracy is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds;

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri That's the link I posted in my answer :). But it doesn't explain how datetime is stored, and why you have these increments.